# TI Design Equation Syntax Question

Tags: design, photodiode, texas-instruments

Have been reviewing the TI Designs – Precision: Verified Design - 1 MHz, Single-Supply, Photodiode Amplifier Reference Design.  In one of the equations (See embedded graphic below), there is a syntax that I have not seen before:

(R2||R3)

It looks like the result is close to the modulus 13700 mod 280 (result **260**) but when I work backwards, I get 1/(2*pi*1/1e6 * **274.3902**) == 580.028Hz so it isnt the modulus.

Does anyone know what specifically it is?

[image: The Algorithm]

Comment: \$ \large R_2 \text{||} R_3  = \frac{R_2 \times R_3}{ R_2 + R_3} \$ It gives the equivalent resistance of two resistors connected in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the Parallel combination of R2 and R3,  or R2*R3/(R2+R3)